# automake needs makeinfo while texinfo needs aclocal

Tags: automake

I am installing packages on a machine without internet access and want to install automake. But I get following error message:

```
WARNING: 'makeinfo' is missing on your system.

         You should only need it if you modified a '.texi' file, or

         any other file indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual.

         You might want to install the Texinfo package:

         <http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/>

         The spurious makeinfo call might also be the consequence of

         using a buggy 'make' (AIX, DU, IRIX), in which case you might

         want to install GNU make:

         http://www.gnu.org/software/make/
```

Therefore I try to make texinfo where I get following error:

```
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.16' is missing on your system.

         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or

         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.

         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:

         <https://www.gnu.org/software/automake>

         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:

         <https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>

         <https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>

         <https://www.perl.org/>
```

Apparently both programs need each other, which I don't understand.

Help is appreciated a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify: are you trying to install them from repositories or from distributed tarballs?

texinfo shouldn't need `aclocal` when building from a tarball.

Comment: Exactly how did you try to install these programs? What commands did you use? Nonetheless, these are just warning, so they shouldn't prevent installation,

Comment: Ok, the warning is followed by this error-message:
```make: *** [Makefile:2506: doc/automake.info] Error127```
bzw. ```make: *** [Makefile:1197: aclocal.m4] Error127```

I installed both from tarballs. Here are the sources:

```
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.16.tar.gz (https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/)
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/texinfo/texinfo-6.7.tar.gz (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/texinfo/)
```
On both I did: tar xvzf * --> ./configure --> make

Comment: Actually, there is more than two programs involved: gnu make, autoconf, automake, m4, perl, texinfo are all required. Maybe you could start here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-linux-applications-downloads-alpha

Comment: circular dependencies are not unheard of. however, it is very uncommon to to install all the dependencies from sources (thankfully gentoo is long gone).